# Is there a way to map differently named environment variables to an IOptions<T> implementation pattern?

Tags: .net-core

Given a .NET Core project using a HostBuilder, with the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2), is there a way to map specific environment variables to my options' properties.

Let's say my options class looks like this:

```
class MyOptions
{
    public string MyFirstValue { get; set; }
    public string MySecondValue { get; set; }
}
```

My `appsettings.json` files can now contain values named `MyFirstValue` and `MySecondValue` (case insensitive), and also be located in sub sections. But what if optional environment variables can override these values, but their name doesn't match the properties? Let's say the first one can be overridden by a `MY_SPECIAL_FIRST_VALUE`? Is there any way to configure my builders to consider this?

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a built-in way to do this, but one option for achieving  this is to register a `Configure`delegate that imperatively overrides the value accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box there is no way to do this because the [environment variable provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environment-variables-configuration-provider) doesn't support it. It requires a pattern to the environment variable name where each level is separated by a double underscore, e.g. `SOME__THING__PROPERTY`.

You could, at a point in the startup before the environment variable provider kicks in, read the value of your custom environment variable and set the appropriate underscored variable, or you could use a delegate as suggested in the comments.

Another option would be to write your own provider, perhaps subclassing [the existing one](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/master/src/Config.EnvironmentVariables/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider.cs) but allowing for custom environment variables. That's obviously a bit more involved.